# Adding colon (:) to Remark Text [Sabre Web Services]

Tags: sabre

In adding a remark using UpdateReservationRQ SOAP API, there is an error returned when the text includes a colon. Is there a way to have the colon in the RQ accepted?

RQ:

```
<v1:UpdateReservationRQ Version="1.18.0">
         <v1:RequestType commitTransaction="false">Stateful</v1:RequestType>
         <v1:ReturnOptions IncludeUpdateDetails="true" RetrievePNR="true" ReturnLocator="true">
            <v1:ViewName>Full</v1:ViewName>
          <v1:ResponseFormat>STL</v1:ResponseFormat>
         </v1:ReturnOptions>
         <v1:ReservationUpdateList>
            <v1:ReservationUpdateItem UpdateId="u4">
               <v1:RemarkUpdate id="4" type="REG" op="C">
                  <v1:RemarkText>Baggage Claim WI1MCJAW created on 2018-11-30T08:30:22Z</v1:RemarkText>
               </v1:RemarkUpdate>
            </v1:ReservationUpdateItem>
            <v1:ReceivedFrom>
               <v1:AgentName>NT3.0</v1:AgentName>
            </v1:ReceivedFrom>
         </v1:ReservationUpdateList>
      </v1:UpdateReservationRQ>
```

RS:

```
<stl18:UpdateReservationRS xmlns:or112="http://services.sabre.com/res/or/v1_12" xmlns:ns4="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrconn/ReaccSearch" xmlns:raw="http://tds.sabre.com/itinerary" xmlns:ns6="http://services.sabre.com/res/orr/v0" xmlns:stl18="http://webservices.sabre.com/pnrbuilder/v1_18">
         <stl18:Success>FALSE</stl18:Success>
         <stl18:Warnings>
            <stl18:Warning>
               <stl18:Message>Partial Error</stl18:Message>
            </stl18:Warning>
         </stl18:Warnings>
         <stl18:Errors>
            <stl18:Error UpdateId="u4">
               <stl18:Code>500900</stl18:Code>
               <stl18:Message>.FRMT</stl18:Message>
            </stl18:Error>
         </stl18:Errors>
         <stl18:Results>
            <stl18:UpdateResult UpdateId="U4" Status="FAILURE">
               <stl18:Item op="C"/>
            </stl18:UpdateResult>
         </stl18:Results>
      </stl18:UpdateReservationRS>
```

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, the colon (:) is not allowed in Sabre on the remark line. The solution is to switch to a different allowed character.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is likely going to come up for a lot of folks, the allowed character set in Sabre can be found [here](https://sds.sabre.com/XTRANET_Access/sabre.htm) (valid as of 12/11/18). Additionally, some fields allow specific characters - the PE field for Emails allow the @ symbol whereas the rest of Sabre does not. All of the strange Sabre characters are also below in an Imgur link that may be more stable than the hyperlink above.

---

[image]

Comment: That is helpful @drtrobridge. Thanks for sharing.